# Knockout observableArray not updating all properties on checked value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm using Knockout to populate an observableArray based on the checked values of a separate observableArray. I can get the $data to copy over into the second set, but only one property comes through. I would like to have the entire object available. Is this a mapping issue, or something with the bindings?

HTML:

```
    <form role="form" data-bind="foreach: Colors">
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: name, click: $root.ToggleAssociation, checked: $root.ColorChoice">
      <label data-bind="attr: {'for' : name}, text: id() + ' ' + name()"></label>
    </form>
    <div data-bind="foreach: ColorChoice">
      <span data-bind="text: $rawData.Id, style: { 'background-color': $rawData.Name }"></span>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function Color(data) {
      var self = this;

      self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
      self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
      self.selected = ko.observable(false);
    }

    function viewModel() {

      var self = this;

      self.Colors = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.ColorChoice = ko.observableArray();

      self.Id = ko.observable();
      self.Color = ko.observable();

      self.init = function () {
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 1, name: 'Red' }));
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 2, name: 'Orange' }));
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 3, name: 'Yellow' }));
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 4, name: 'Green' }));
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 5, name: 'Blue' }));
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 6, name: 'Purple' }));
      }

      self.ToggleAssociation = function (item) {
        if (item.selected() === true)
          console.log("dissociate item " + item.id());
        else
          console.log("associate item " + item.id() + " " + item.name());
        self.Id(item.id());
        self.Color(item.name());
        item.selected(!(item.selected()));
        return true;
      };
    };

    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    vm.init();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Razzle/ff1945ye/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an access to all of your variables in your model.
If I am understanding exactly what you are trying to do and you would like to bind the `click` event whenever the checkbox is checked, you need to do something like this .

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/77/

**HTML:**

```
<form role="form" data-bind="foreach: Colors">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: name, click: $root.ToggleAssociation ,checked:selected">
  <label data-bind="attr: {'for' : name}, text: id() + ' ' + name()"></label>
</form>
<div data-bind="foreach: ColorChoice">
  <span data-bind="text: name, style: { 'background-color':name }" class="colors"></span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
 function Color(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  self.selected = ko.observable(false);
}

function viewModel() {

  var self = this;

  self.Colors = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.ColorChoice = ko.observableArray();

  self.Id = ko.observable();
  self.Color = ko.observable();

  self.init = function () {
    self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 1, name: 'Red' }));
    self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 2, name: 'Orange' }));
    self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 3, name: 'Yellow' }));
    self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 4, name: 'Green' }));
    self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 5, name: 'Blue' }));
    self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 6, name: 'Purple' }));
  }

  self.ToggleAssociation = function (item) {
   // here you can go through your array and do whatever you want to do
    item.selected(!item.selected());
     ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Colors(), function (color) {
      if(color.id() == item.id()){
       if (item.selected()){self.ColorChoice.push(color);
       }else{self.ColorChoice.remove(color);
       }
      }
     });
    return true;
  };
};

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.init();
```

Comment: Nice--thanks! So the ko.utils.arrayFirst is checking the secondary array to see if the item matches up?

Comment: `ko.utils.arrayFirst`  executes a function against each item in the array and returns the first item where the function evaluates to `true`. We are iterating through the main array and whatever matches the selected item we push into the second array and if it is not selected we remove from it.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, again.

Comment: Updated your fiddle with a 'return: true' on line 37, as it was not checking the actual box. https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/77/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in much simpler way like below

```js
function Color(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.selected = ko.observable(false);
}

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Colors = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.ColorChoice = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.init = function() {
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 1, name: 'Red' }));
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 2, name: 'Orange' }));
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 3, name: 'Yellow' }));
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 4, name: 'Green' }));
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 5, name: 'Blue' }));
        self.Colors.push(new Color({ id: 6, name: 'Purple' }));
    }
};

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form role="form" data-bind="foreach: Colors">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data, checked:$root.ColorChoice">
        <span data-bind="text: id() + ' ' + name()"></span>
    </label>
</form>
<div data-bind="foreach: ColorChoice">
    <span data-bind="text: id() + ' ' + name(), style: { 'background-color':name }"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a simple solution, but I do need to keep the click event in there. It was helpful to see the stripped down version, though.